# C#.net VS2010 Dynamic Wizard Content

Tags: c#, .net, forms, dynamic, frame

What I am looking to to is to put a frame in my window, and then fill the frame with different preset content from other forms.

For example the welcome page of the wizard, I want it to say welcome,and a little about my program. When the user clicks the next button(located outside of the frame, but inside the window) the frame will show content from the next form(that I already made in the designer).

Is this possible, and what code/resources would I need to accomplish this task? Would it be easier to just dynamically add the items?

Thank you,
pseudoSequential

Answer (score 0):

Try this I used it and it is great just be sure to correct the spelling before you compile the DLL's http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ak_wizard.aspx